# SharePoint Form Library files cannot be edited in IE

Tags: sharepoint

Could anyone advise what settings need to be checked?

My form library on SharePoint 2013 can create new files in the published form. 
But when click on a file, it opens as plain xml in IE; also can be edited in InfoPath if it is installed. But cannot be edited in IE.

Checked: Use the server default (Open in the browser)

There are other form libraries work fine on the same server.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the subsite template is wrong (but it cannot be changed). Created a new subsite of Document Center, then it works.